# Why my laravel app homepage redirect 404 on subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My laravel app .htaccess is below...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule \.(env)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

The case problem is...
I have a sample domain named example.com, I try to install app using laravel framework and works well. (dir folder in public_html/{laravel_app})

Then, I try to add subdomain like subdomain.example.com and copy all laravel app data into (dir public_html/subdomain/{laravel_app})

The problem is... 
if I access example.com/subdomain/ => showing homepage of laravel app (done)
But, If I access subdomain.example.com => redirect to 404(normally showing homepage)

Thanks... for your attention :-)

Comment: Have you looked into Laravel's [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)?

Comment: not yet. There is any subdomain route for laravel?. can you explain me?

Comment: I've never used it, so the only information I could give is from the link above and anything found on google.